# Is it required to assign a "threadhandle" to null after calling Closehandle(threadhandle)?

Tags: windows, multithreading, thread-safety, desktop-application

```
HANDLE threadHandle = CreateThread(?, ?, ?, .......);
SetThreadPriority(threadHandle, priority);
CloseHandle(threadHandle);
threadHandle = NULL;
............
```

Comment: A handle is usually just an integer (OK, sometimes its a pointer but a pointer is also an integer after all...) from your point of view and it is usually meaningful only for the API that provides you with the handle and it is a meaningful number even for the API only until closing it. It is usually a good practice to null it out, it helps debugging and also makes some related runtime bugs (double closing reused handle) less prominent.

Comment: How about the second usage I added? Is that usage valid? Because closehandle does not terminate the thread. If so how can I deal with setting the threadhandle to null?

Comment: The second usage is invalid because after closing the handle the value of the handle is meaningless for the API. In worst case the API has already reused the previously closed handle value and then your SetThreadPriority() call changes the priority for a handle that isn't yours. Of course most APIs use some time delay when reusing handle values but some APIs don't, for example in case of opengl you can easily run into the problem of closing reused handles and then you will see strange textures/images appearing in your rendered scene...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a requirement - just a potential debugging aid.